# Saving files in file system in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, nestjs

I want to store the `URL` of images sent from client using `multipart/form-data`in my `MySQL` database. I followed the docs but I can't really find out how I should save an image in server file system and return the URL back to the client.

This is my code:

```
@ApiTags('product-image')
@Controller('product-image')
export class ProductImageController {
  constructor(public service: ProductImageService) {
  }

  @Post('upload')
  @UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
  uploadImage(@UploadedFiles() files) {
    console.log(files);
    // How can I save image files in
    // a custom path and return the path
    // back to the client?

  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this

```
import { FilesInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { diskStorage } from 'multer';

@Post('upload')
    @UseInterceptors(
        FilesInterceptor('files', 20, {
          storage: diskStorage({
            destination: './uploads/',
            filename: editFileName,
          }),
        //   fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
        }),
      )
      uploadMultipleFiles(@UploadedFiles() files) {
        const response = [];
        files.forEach(file => {
          const fileReponse = {
            filename: file.filename,
          };
          response.push(fileReponse);
        });
        return response;
      }
```

Comment: Another question though: how can I return an image to the client? in express, we usually do `res.end()`, how can I return an image in nestjs?

Comment: @Get('image/:imgpath')
    seeUploadedFile(@Param('imgpath') image, @Res() res) {
      return res.sendFile(image, { root: './uploads' });
    }

Comment: how can i move the save logic to service?